# Permission needed for using GetTableNames

Tags: delphi, c++builder, sap-ase, firedac, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a Delphi/C++ builder app that uses Firedac to connect to a Sybase ASE database using the ODBC connection. When connection to the database, if I use the database's system admin (SA) user id/password, everything works fine and `GetTableNames` comes back with the list of tables in the database. But if I use a regular user to connect to database, `GetTableNames` comes back with an empty list. My question is, what permissions should I give the regular user for this to work.
And as a side question, does anyone know what kind of command Firedac sends to database to get the table names?
My code in Delphi looks like:

```
DBConnection.GetTableNames('', '', '', tableNameList, [TFDPhysObjectScope.osMy], [TFDPhysTableKind.tkTable]);
```

and in C++ Builder it looks like:

```
DBConnection->GetTableNames(L"", L"", L"", tableNameList, TFDPhysObjectScopes() << TFDPhysObjectScope::osMy, TFDPhysTableKinds() << TFDPhysTableKind::tkTable);
```

Thank you
Sam

Comment: to assign permissions to a non-sa user would require knowing the actual command being run in the database (eg, a stored proc call? a select from system tables?); the easiest way to track down the SQL would be to configure ASE to enable MDA tables and then after the GetTableNames invocation, pull the text from `master..monSysSQLText where ServerUserID = suser_id(<non-sa-login>)`

Answer (score 1):

For generic ODBC drivers it's the [**SQLTables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqltables-function) function that FireDAC calls. Unfortunately, for the SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise driver I haven't found any information about the implementation of this function. It is the implementation detail, so it's not the issue.

The only note I found is this (for different products), for example:

> **[sp_tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38454.1570/doc/html/san1339532730598.html)**
>
> This function corresponds to the ODBC function SQLTables.

So it's possible that the ODBC driver calls the [**sp_tables**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38454.1570/doc/html/san1339532730598.html) stored procedure in its [**SQLTables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqltables-function) function implementation for that product, but no one explicitly said that (only that it corresponds).

What's more, for SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise, there is no such note by its [**sp_tables**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1600/doc/html/san1393052114903.html) procedure. But you can give it a try. Or better yet, if you have some kind of command monitoring tool, use it to track what your driver calls from its [**SQLTables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqltables-function) function implementation.

In any case, it is an implementation detail you should not care about, nor rely on.

Comment: +1.  I was wondering about sp_tables, seeing as Sql Server 6.5 was a derivative of the prior Sybase product, but your alternative of watching what calls are actually made to the server might be a better way to go.

Comment: @MartynA, thank you :) But it's just a wild guess. OP should better track this down by some command monitor. And even then, a new driver version can e.g. implement that ODBC function in a different way. The most important point is, I'd say, that it's an implementation detail.

Comment: Indeed.  Personally, if I ran into a problem getting a list of table names in an FD project, I'd be tempted to get the list via ADO.  With ADO I always feel that there's "safety in numbers" (of users).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was NOT permissions, it was the 5th parameter of [GetTableNames](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.GetTableNames). The 5th parameter is the Scope which determines what kind of tables would be reported back. `osMy` means tables/objects owned by the logged-in user. But normally all tables in a database, are owned by `SA/dbo`. Adding `osOther` to the parameter will fix the problem. So the correct way of calling the function in Delphi would be:

```
DBConnection.GetTableNames('', '', '', tableNameList, [TFDPhysObjectScope.osMy, TFDPhysObjectScope.osOther], [TFDPhysTableKind.tkTable]);
```

and in C++ Builder it should look like:

```
DBConnection->GetTableNames(L"", L"", L"", tableNameList, TFDPhysObjectScopes() << TFDPhysObjectScope::osMy << TFDPhysObjectScope::osOther, TFDPhysTableKinds() << TFDPhysTableKind::tkTable);
```

Which will return the name of all tables that are not system tables.
I must mention that I blame Embarcadero for poor documentation of [TFDPhysObjectScope](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Phys.Intf.TFDPhysObjectScope). The documentation does NOT explain what any of these values means. Way too often (as in this case) we see this:

> Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional
>   information. Please help us document this topic by using the
>   Discussion page!

And we are forced to guess and/or try-fail.